# Angular click event Dom Unit Test with Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test a simple click event from a simple button component. With karma + jasmine, it is very straight forward, but I do not get it with jest.

Here is the button component I want to test:

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ui-button',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() public click = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor() {}

  public ngOnInit() {}
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" click="click.emit($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

Now I want to test, if the EventEmitter is firing, when I click the button:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';

describe('ButtonComponent', () => {
  let component: ButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ButtonComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ButtonComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should fire a click event', (done) => {
    component.click.subscribe((event: any) => {
      expect(event).toBeDefined();
      done();
    });
    const htmlButton: HTMLButtonElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    htmlButton.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
});
```

Test fails, because the event is never firing as you can see in my log output:

```
 FAIL  libs/ui/src/lib/button/button.component.spec.ts (9.668s)
  ● ButtonComponent › should fire a click event

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

      31 |   });
      32 |
    > 33 |   it('should fire a click event', (done) => {
         |   ^
      34 |     component.click.subscribe((event: any) => {
      35 |       expect(event).toBeTruthy();
      36 |       done();

      at new Spec (../../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at env.(anonymous function) (../../node_modules/jest-preset-angular/zone-patch/index.js:84:27)
      at src/lib/button/button.component.spec.ts:33:3
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:43)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/jest-preset-angular/zone-patch/index.js:40:21)
      at env.(anonymous function) (../../node_modules/jest-preset-angular/zone-patch/index.js:69:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/button/button.component.spec.ts:4:1)
```

What do I need to change, so that my event is firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how it could works with karma/jasmine ?

I think that's because of your usage of event emitter :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="click.emit($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

Otherwise your test seems to be good

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out, but it works in the browser on manual click. But of course you are right. The thing is, it is still not working and still giving me the same Timeout.

Comment: And if you try to call `fixture.detectChanges();` before clicking on the button ?

Comment: Ok sorry, didn't see it. So now try to use `debugElement` instead of `nativeElement` to query elements : `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement`

Comment: Already tried this. Also tried to dispatchEvent() or triggerEventHandler() with all those different elements.

Comment: Just to be sure : have you wrapped in click with parenthesis in your template ? I've seen that you've updated your question with `.emit($event)` but not with parenthesis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196719/discussion-between-florian-leitgeb-and-martin-choraine).